# Spring Security Database authentication

Tags: database, spring, security

When I use an in memory xml username/password to autheticate it works, so the next stage for my project was to authenticate against a database. This is where I come up with persistent problems. It has been days.

Output in the console which tells me that it is at least connecting to my database b/c that is the username I insert in the mysql db.

```
  loadUserByUsername  :  ed23
```

But instead of authenticating it returns the login failed page even though the username/password are correct.

Security xml

```
   <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

   <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/denied">


    <intercept-url pattern='/main/home.jsp' access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" /> 
    <intercept-url pattern='/admin/admin.jsp' access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

    <form-login login-page='/login.jsp' always-use-default-target="true" default-

  target-url="/main/home" authentication-failure-url="/login_error.jsp?error=true"/>   

    <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url='/login.jsp' /> 



  </http>

  <!-- authentication manager and password hashing -->
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider ref="daoAuthenticationProvider"/>
 </authentication-manager>

  <beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" 

  class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
  <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
  <beans:property name="saltSource">
    <beans:bean 

   class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.ReflectionSaltSource">
        <beans:property name="userPropertyToUse" value="username"/>
    </beans:bean>
 </beans:property>
 <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder"/>
 </beans:bean>

 <beans:bean id="userDetailsService"    

 class="com.project.professional.service.StaffServiceImpl">

  </beans:bean>

 <beans:bean id="passwordEncoder" 

 class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder">
 <beans:constructor-arg index="0" value="256"/>
 </beans:bean>
```

Login jsp

```
     <form action="${loginUrl}" method="post" name="loginForm">

    <p>
    <label for="j_username">Username</label>
    <input id="j_username" name="j_username" type="text" />
    </p>

    <p>
    <label for="j_password">Password</label>
    <input id="j_password" name="j_password" type="password" />
    </p>

   <input  type="submit  

   value="Login"/>                              

    </form>
```

Controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/main/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getHomePage(Locale locale, Model model) {

    return "/main/home";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getLoginPage(ModelMap model) {
    logger.info("This is the login page {}.");

    return "login";

}
```

Userdetails implementation

```
       public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("loadUserByUsername  :  " + username);
        //DAO<Staff> sessionFactory = null;
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        username = (username == null) ? "" : username;
        Query query = session
            .createQuery("from Staff where username=:username");
        query.setParameter("username", username);

        if (query.list().isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        return (UserDetails) query.list().get(0);

    }


       public Staff getStaffDetails(String username) {
       Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery("from Staff where username=:username");
    query.setParameter("username", username);

    if (query.list().isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    return (Staff) query.list().get(0);
```

I can access the pages from the navigation bar, but I cant secure it so that they are only accessed if authenticated from the login page. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> HTTP status 404

means that the page is not found. This could happen when 1) the page is not there! (which is most probable) 2) the server is not started correctly (which I doubt, since in that case you would have noticed)

So I suggest you to check your `login_error.jsp` page location. It might not be in the right place where you wanted it to be.

Comment: I have checked and the jsp is where I want it to be. I can also access it manually. But the authentication error is not returning it or returning the home page when I use the correct username/password

Comment: Okay I removed the .jsp from the authentication-failure-url and now it returns the custom login error page. But the problem now is the username/password I used is correct but it's not working.